# How to persist data with Serializable interface in java android

Tags: android

I have a problem that, I have a webservice which returns 3 arrays from JSON response. I want to persist those lists from one class to another in our android app with the help of Serializable interface and Setter and Getter Methods. But I don't know how to achieve this? Please help me out about this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` or `Sqlite` can be the way you can use to store persist data.

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)  for persist data between Activities.

Some examples for Shared Preferences

[Example1](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html)

[Example 2](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/63.html)

Some examples for Sqlite

[Example 1](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742)

[Example 2](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/)

[Example 3](http://www.helloandroid.com/taxonomy/term/19)

Comment: I want to persist data in our app not to pass data from one activity to another. Can you give me the idea about persisting data without static variables?

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences for persist data between Activity or Sqlite also.

Comment: Sqlite also is a good option check the links that I had provided.

Comment: I can not use Sqlite because this is my restriction. Can give me the idea behind the Serializable class and how to make that with arraylists for setting and getting the desired values.

Comment: In Android you can use Parcelable instead of Serealizable that I opted you before.